# Cmake external shared library not linking on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I give up, can't sort this out for several days. I am building shared .so library (dayaswig ) on ubuntu, and want to include other external shared library (dayagame). CMakeLists.txt  code is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project (dayaswig LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 0.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
 set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -ggdb -pg -fsanitize=undefined")
 set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2")
 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG})
 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE})
endif ()
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE)

set(BASE_DIR ./)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
find_package(dayagame REQUIRED)


get_filename_component(HEADERS src REALPATH)
include_directories(${HEADERS} ${DAYAGAME_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(SOURCE_FILES helloworld.hpp helloworld.cpp helloworld_wrap.cxx)

add_library(dayaswig SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_library(dayagame SHARED IMPORTED)

target_include_directories (dayaswig PUBLIC ${BASE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(dayaswig LINK_PUBLIC ${DAYAGAME_LIBRARY})

install(TARGETS dayaswig DESTINATION /usr/lib)
```

and find module code is

```
find_path(DAYAGAME_INCLUDE_DIR dayaserver.hpp PATHS "/usr/local/include/dayagame/")
find_library(DAYAGAME_LIBRARY dayagame PATHS "/usr/local/lib")

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(DAYAGAME DEFAULT_MSG DAYAGAME_LIBRARY DAYAGAME_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

All builds fine, except that dayagame library is never linked with dayaswig. Any help is really appreciated.

If I print all variables, I can see, that they are resolved just fine:

```
-- DAYAGAME_FOUND=TRUE
-- DAYAGAME_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include/dayagame
-- DAYAGAME_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libdayagame.so
```

Comment: "... except that dayagame library is never linked with dayaswig." - How do you deduce that? Do you have an error from the linker about "undefined reference" or so? If you build the project with `make`, you may run `make VERBOSE` and check actual command line used for linking `dayaswig` library.

Comment: Does your `dayaswig` actually import symbols from `dayagame` ?  If not, you may be running into trouble with the default `--as-needed` option for your linker. Try adding `--no-as-needed` to your `LDFLAGS`. (Or actually import symbols)